# RegEx string splitting and concatenating

Tags: regex, string, split, regex-group

I am trying to split and re-concatenate a string to get a snippet of a URI.

I start from a simple ID of 16 characters and I have to divide it into 8 pairs of characters, for example from
`0b00271180119cce`
to
`0b/00/27/11/80/11/9c/ce/`

Is there any way to achieve this using **only** a RegEx instruction?

Using something like
`([A-z0-9]{1,2})`
I got a group with 8 matches but I don't know how to recombine them into a string with a separator ("/" in this specific case).

*I am afraid that none of the indications below are directly usable in my context. The problem is that I can't use any of the usual programming languages (Java, JavaScript, PHP and so on), because the RegEx instruction has to be used inside a parameter in a Documentum D2 configuration (an Autonaming, to be exact ).*

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `ce7` is a typo? Where does 7 come from? Seems liike https://regex101.com/r/28SioG/1 should work... assuming there is a typo

Comment: There are duplicated and unwanted characters (```[`\]^_```) in the `[A-zA-z-0-9]` class. Use `[A-Z0-9]` with the `i` flag, or, if that's not possible, `[A-Za-z0-9]`.

Comment: Try `(\w\w)(\w\w)(\w\w)(\w\w)(\w\w)(\w\w)(\w\w)(\w\w)`

Answer (score 1):

Given:

```js
const id = "0b00271180119cce";
```

use the regex below:

```js
const regex = /([A-Z0-9]{2})/ig;
```

- Note: this regex avoids duplicated and unwanted characters as mentioned in another user's comment on your question, but for this case `const regex = /([a-zA-Z0-9]{2})/g;` would have also worked.

---

**Option 1**

The simplest way to match the regex and recombine into a string with a separator ("/" in this specific case) is using a regex `replace` and inserting the matched capture group followed by a slash into the output string. Here's an example in JavaScript:

```js
const result = id.replace(regex, "$1/");
```

- Note: above uses `$n` where `n` is the group number

**Option 2**

You can also achieve this using a regex `replace` with a function as the second argument:

```js
const result = id.replace(regex, (match, group) => `${group}/`);
```

- Note: a function is overkill if you just want to copy the match or capture group into the replacement, so go with option 1. This is just demonstrating an alternative way to accomplish your goal.

---

You can `console.log` both `result`s to observe the desired output:

```js
console.log(result); // "0b/00/27/11/80/11/9c/ce/"
```

```js
const id = "0b00271180119cce";
const regex = /([A-Z0-9]{2})/ig;

let result = id.replace(regex, "$1/");
console.log(result);

result = id.replace(regex, (match, group) => `${group}/`);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: @Barmar updated my answer to include your input

Answer (score 1):

Use a back-reference in the replacement string. `$&` refers to what was matched by the regexp.

```js
let string = '0b00271180119cce';
let new_string = string.replace(/.{1,2}/g, '$&/');
console.log(new_string);
```